# how to use WebDriverBacked Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I have been trying to find a way to test an application that will only open on IE and the application has pages rendered in Silverlight looked at the silvernium but could not get it to work as when I run it there is a missing dll.so I found out about the WebdriverBackedSelenium which I have tried to use but I get the error

```
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll
    Cannot find a file   named 'C:\Users\.nuget\packages\selenium.webdriver\3.14.0\lib\netstandard2.0\isTextPresent.js' or an embedded resource with the id 'isTextPresent.js
```

here is my code just simple code to get me started my aim is to be able to test the Silverlight part of the application

```
    browser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        browser.Start();
        browser.Open(url);
```

the error is being flagged when I initialise the browser here

```
     browser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);
```

any help and resources to read will be appreciated thanks in advance please not I am using c# even java examples are appreciated

Comment: Why not use MicrosoftWebDriver?

Comment: Two things: First, WebDriverBackedSelenium has not, in general, been tested under .NET Core. Second, even if you can get it to work, it won't be able to automate Silverlight objects anymore than WebDriver can automate Flash objects. They're opaque to WebDriver, and the internals cannot be inspected by the driver code.