# Missing .js files for Selenium in .Net causing test failures

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run some basic Selenium tests in .Net Core with the Nunit test framework.

I have these Nuget packages installed:

```
Selenium.Support
Selenium.Helper
Selenium.WebDriver
Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver
Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium
```

When running any unit test I get

```
"Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot find a file named 
'D:\SeleniumTests\SeleniumTests.OldFramework\bin\Debug\isTextPresent.js' or 
an embedded resource with the id 'isTextPresent.js'."
```

Searching online did not help. I found this
[how to use WebDriverBacked Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670269/how-to-use-webdriverbacked-selenium)
, I tried the one suggestion included but that did not resolve the issue. I also recreated the test in .Net Framework to see if it was a Core issue, still seeing the failures.

There isn't much documentation on missing this file, I expected them to come through in a Nuget package, installing manually doesn't seem very maintainable, and I did not see a single guide that mentioned installing js files manually.

Here is my one test.

```
[TestCase]
public async Task ChromeTest1()
{

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    var sometthing = new Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://www.google.com");

    sometthing.Click(By.LinkText("Search").ToString());

    driver.Quit();
    sometthing.Close();

    Assert.True(sometthing.GetTitle() == "");
}
```

Is there some secret to getting this to work? Am I doing it wrong? Is Selenium just a hoax by the Chinese?

Comment: WebDriverBackedSelenium relies on a fair amount of JavaScript code. The code is supposed to be generated by the Selenium build process (which requires steps external to Visual Studio). The subsequent JavaScript files should be embedded in the assembly before it’s released via NuGet. Of course, it’s entirely possible that something unforeseen has changed that causes this not to be so.

Answer (score 0):

I could only work around it by downgrading to WebDriverBackedSelenium version 3.5.2. From version 3.6.0 onwards, I get messages about missing .js files.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Because you didn't provide enough detail as to WHY.

Comment: So for my understanding - if I know a potential solution to help some people out but I don't know why it works, I shouldn't post it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Because while it may seem very helpful (and I understand that's all you were trying to do), it might actually not be the answer. - It might just look as though it works, or work under a very strict set of conditions. Until you understand WHY something is doing what it's doing, you shouldn't really be suggesting it as the final answer. It would be like taking medicine, and also sniffing a flower - then when you get better, if you don't know its the medicine that fixed you, you may suggest sniffing flowers to someone else, because that correlated with working for you.